# TFS 2013: How to find Tasks without parent Bugs and with child TestCases

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Recently we started using TFS as bug tracker, and faced some problems with making queries for work items. One of problems is described in header of this topic.

Can anyone help with such query?

Thank you.

Comment: Will you please explain what actually you problem ...

Comment: My problem is that i can't figure out how to create query, that will return Tasks, which has no parent Bug, but same time has child TestCase. Query editor in TFS Web Access allows only one condition applying to linked work items. I mean that we can get Tasks, wich has no parent Bug OR Tasks which has child TestCase, but i wonder, how to combine this conditions in one query.

Comment: Have you tried using the 'Tree of Work Items' query type, instead of the flat list?

Comment: Yes, i'm talking about this type of query

Comment: The backlog view will show you unparented tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately both the vs query editor and the tfs workitem engine do NOT allow this kind of query out-of-the-box.
You can achieve that result only by creating some custom code that uses the tfs api to execute two queries ad intersect their results.
If you are interested in how to do it, I can provide an example.
However keep in mind that - in this way - the query would be stand alone and not integrated in the visual studio ide.

Comment: I would LOVE an example!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do both of these tests together, but I have been able to write a query to find bugs without a child task, which is similar to your problem. Attached is a picture showing my solution.

[image]